# What is the difference between delete and delete[]?

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

What is the difference between `delete` and `delete[]` operators in C++?

Comment: You might find this question relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913343/how-could-pairing-new-with-delete-possibly-lead-to-memory-leak-only

Comment: The issues with delete and delete[] are one reason why I like smart pointers, and using `vector<>` instead of an array whenever I can.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/pod-freeing-memory-is-delete-equal-to-delete

Comment: @DavidThornley If you're using smart pointers you still need to know the difference in the sense that you still need to know not to write e.g. `std::unique_ptr<int>(new int[3])`, because it will call regular `delete` on the array which is undefined behaviour. Instead you need to use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`

Comment: @DavidThornley You should probably use `std::array` when you know the size beforehand since it matches that use case better conceptually and will most likely be faster to boot.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The `delete` operator deallocates memory and calls the destructor for a single object created with `new`.

The `delete []` operator deallocates memory and calls destructors for an array of objects created with `new []`.

Using `delete` on a pointer returned by `new []` or `delete []` on a pointer returned by `new` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I wonder if using delete on a new[] array of primitive types like int or char (no constructor/destructor) necessarily leads to undefined behavior, too. It seems the array size isn't stored anywhere when using primitive types.

Comment: If the standard doesn't define what happens when that is done, it is by definition "undefined behavior", even if your compiler deterministically does what you'd like it to do. Another compiler may do something entirely different.

Comment: I made this error when I had an array of C strings like "char** strArray". If you have an array like I do, you need to iterate through the array and delete/free each element, then delete/free the strArray itself. Using "delete[]" on the array I have does not work since (as pointed out by the above comments and answer), IT CALLS DESTRUCTORS, it doesn't actually free each slot.

Answer (score 110):

The `delete[]` operator is used to delete arrays. The `delete` operator is used to delete non-array objects. It calls `operator delete[]` and `operator delete` function respectively to delete the memory that the array or non-array object occupied after (eventually) calling the destructors for the array's elements or the non-array object.

The following shows the relations:

```
typedef int array_type[1];

// create and destroy a int[1]
array_type *a = new array_type;
delete [] a;

// create and destroy an int
int *b = new int;
delete b;

// create and destroy an int[1]
int *c = new int[1];
delete[] c;

// create and destroy an int[1][2]
int (*d)[2] = new int[1][2];
delete [] d;
```

For the `new` that creates an array (so, either the `new type[]` or `new` applied to an array type construct), the Standard looks for an `operator new[]` in the array's element type class or in the global scope, and passes the amount of memory requested. It may request more than `N * sizeof(ElementType)` if it wants (for instance to store the number of elements, so it later when deleting knows how many destructor calls to done). If the class declares an `operator new[]` that additional to the amount of memory accepts another `size_t`, that second parameter will receive the number of elements allocated - it may use this for any purpose it wants (debugging, etc...).

For the `new` that creates a non-array object, it will look for an `operator new` in the element's class or in the global scope. It passes the amount of memory requested (exactly `sizeof(T)` always).

For the `delete[]`, it looks into the arrays' element class type and calls their destructors. The `operator delete[]` function used is the one in the element type's class, or if there is none then in the global scope.

For the `delete`, if the pointer passed is a base class of the actual object's type, the base class must have a virtual destructor (otherwise, behavior is undefined). If it is not a base class, then the destructor of that class is called, and an `operator delete` in that class or the global `operator delete` is used. If a base class was passed, then the actual object type's destructor is called, and the `operator delete` found in that class is used, or if there is none, a global `operator delete` is called. If the `operator delete` in the class has a second parameter of type `size_t`, it will receive the number of elements to deallocate.

Comment: If if I have an array of pointers to objects, each of which may be nullptr, delete[] will not delete the objects pointed at by those pointers, right? delete[] will only delete the array elements which are physically embedded in the array. Like if you have an array of structs, then each struct destructor will get called. But not if you have an array of pointers to structs. The memory for the pointes will be freed, but not the memory for any structs that are pointed at by those pointers.

Answer (score 37):

This the basic usage of allocate/DE-allocate pattern in c++
 `malloc`/`free`, `new`/`delete`, `new[]`/`delete[]`

We need to use them correspondingly. But I would like to add this particular understanding for the difference between `delete` and `delete[]`

1) `delete` is used to de-allocate memory allocated for **single object**

2) `delete[]` is used to de-allocate memory allocated for **array of objects**

```
class ABC{}

ABC *ptr = new ABC[100]
```

when we say `new ABC[100]`, compiler can get the information about how many objects that needs to be allocated(here it is 100) and will call the constructor for each of the objects created

but correspondingly if we simply use `delete ptr` for this case, compiler will not know how many objects that `ptr` is pointing to and will end up calling of destructor and deleting memory for only 1 object(leaving the invocation of destructors and deallocation of remaining 99 objects). Hence there will be a memory leak.

so we need to use `delete [] ptr` in this case.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. None of the other answers mention the distinct difference: "but correspondingly if we simply use delete ptr for this case, compiler will not know how many objects that ptr is pointing to and will end up calling of destructor and deleting memory for only 1 object"

Comment: How do we achieve the same thing in C ?

Comment: @DogusUral Why? There are no destructors in C, so you just `free()` this and that. If you use a pseudo-destructor pattern, you have to call it once for every object using a `for` loop.

Comment: @DonLarynx the *correct* difference is that mixing them up results in an ill-formed program. An implementation *might* know how many objects to destruct, or it *might not*. It is allowed to know that it was called wrong, and abort the program telling you where the problem is.

Answer (score 9):

When I asked this question, my real question was, "is there a difference between the two?  Doesn't the runtime have to keep information about the array size, and so will it not be able to tell which one we mean?"  This question does not appear in "related questions", so just to help out those like me, here is the answer to that: ["why do we even need the delete[] operator?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252515/why-do-we-even-need-the-delete-operator)

Comment: Thanks for coming back and putting this in.

Answer (score 6):

The operators `delete` and `delete []` are used respectively to destroy the objects created with `new` and `new[]`, returning to the allocated memory left available to the compiler's memory manager.

Objects created with `new` must necessarily be destroyed with `delete`, and that the arrays created with `new[]` should be deleted with `delete[]`.

Answer (score 5):

C++ delete[] operator ensures that Destructor for all object allocated with new[] is called. The following example demonstrates the same. Also, delete[] must be preferred (if new[] used previously) when the class has a non-default destructor to release the acquired resources. Otherwise, it might result in memory leaks.

Common Code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class memTest{
    public:
    static int num;
    memTest(){
cout<<"Constructor from object " << num++ << endl;
    }
    ~memTest(){
cout<<"Destructor from object " << --num << endl;        
    }
};
int memTest::num=0;
```

Example 1:- use of new[] and delete may result in undefined behavior.

```
int main() {
    memTest* Test1=new memTest[3];
    
    delete Test1; //<-----
    return 0;
}
```

Output 1:-

```
Constructor from object 0
Constructor from object 1
Constructor from object 2
Destructor from object 2 //<-----
```

Example 2: The correct behavior is using new[] and delete[].

```
int main() {
    memTest* Test1=new memTest[3];
    
    delete[] Test1; //<-----
    return 0;
}
```

Output 2:-

```
Constructor from object 0
Constructor from object 1
Constructor from object 2
Destructor from object 2
Destructor from object 1 //<-----
Destructor from object 0 //<-----
```

Answer (score -1):

`delete` is used for one single pointer and `delete[]` is used for deleting an array through a pointer.
[This](http://techieswagger.com/technology/memory-management-c-plus-plus/) might help you to understand better.

Comment: The link is broken.