# delete vs delete[]

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the difference between delete and delete[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2425728/5740428)

When I was taught C++, this was a long time ago. I was told to never use `delete` but `delete[]` as performing `delete[]` on a single object will be equivalent to `delete`. Knowing not to trust teachers too much I wonder, Is this true?

Is there ever a reason to call `delete` instead of `delete[]`?

I've scanned the possibly related questions in SO, but haven't found any clear answer.

Comment: /me throws up a little.  Did they recommend you always call new[1] as well?

Comment: Don't trust them when they tell "never". All strong statements are wrong.

Comment: Actually there're small range of cases where you need to use `delete[]` in C++. It is better to use `std::vector` or `boost::array`.

Comment: @Kirill "All strong statements are wrong." this statement is paradoxical.

Comment: If use valgrind --leak-check=full ./(binary name) you will get warning "Mismatched free() / delete / delete []". It is better to compile your program with valgrind to check for memory related queries.

Comment: lol, "All strong statements are wrong", is a strong statement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was his joke.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

From the standard (5.3.5/2) :

> In the first alternative (delete
>   object), the value of the operand of
>   delete shall be a pointer to a
>   non-array object or a pointer to a
>   sub-object (1.8) representing a base
>   class of such an object (clause 10).
>   **If not, the behavior is undefined.**
>
> In the second alternative (delete
>   array), the value of the operand of
>   delete shall be the pointer value
>   which resulted from a previous array
>   new-expression. **If not, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

So no : they are in no way equivalent !

Answer (score 55):

`delete []` is "vector delete" and corresponds to vector new, i.e. `new[]`.

You must use the matching pair of allocators. E.g. `malloc/free`, `new/delete`, `new[]/delete[]`, else you get undefined behavior.

Comment: The word "vector" in the response should be changed to "native C-style array" ? Otherwise it is just a bit confusing perhaps.

Comment: No, vector and scalar new/delete are well understood terms.

Answer (score 36):

No! you call `delete[]` when you allocate with `new[]`, otherwise you call `delete`.

What teacher told you leads to undefined behaviour and, if you are lucky, an application crash.

Answer (score 11):

`delete` is used to delete a single object, while `delete[]` is used to delete an array of objects. Check this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/) for more info.