# c++ array new char [] with boost::shared_array?

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc, new-operator, shared-ptr

### Updated

Will this line of code work:

```
boost::shared_array<struct sockaddr> addr(
    reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(
        (ipv6 ? new unsigned char [sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)]
              : new unsigned char [sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)])
    )
);
```

Note the two different data types between allocation and the type given in the `<template>`.

---

### The original question was with boost::shared_ptr

Will this line of code work:

```
boost::shared_ptr<struct sockaddr> addr(
    reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(
        (ipv6 ? new unsigned char [sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)]
              : new unsigned char [sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)])
    )
);
```

Note the two different data types between allocation and the type given in the `<template>`.

### Solution

```
boost::shared_array<unsigned char> address(new unsigned char [sizeof(sockaddr_in)]);
```

NOTE: The same type of unsigned char is being used with a size exactly of the one that's needed.

and then when I am going to use it:

```
bind(, (sockaddr*)address.get(), );
```

Comment: No. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255598/delete-vs-delete

Comment: Just run it and see what happens.

Comment: @CaseyRobinson: It's not always possible to see undefined behaviour.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because you didn't present much of your own research effort, or more detailed explanations like your ideas on the topic, just a snippet of code (or because people don't like undefined behaviour in C++ :-)). Your question is a valid question though, so don't worry.

Comment: @BoPersson The manpages for `bind()` tell you to explictly do just that, cast a `sockaddr_in6 *` to `sockaddr *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is incorrect. At one point the smart pointer would try to do something like:

```
sockaddr* data;
// ...
delete data; // boom!
```

Your buffer needs to be deleted another way (with `delete[]` not `delete` and through a pointer of a correct type).

Have a look at `boost::shared_array`, maybe that's what you actually need.

---

After your edits and the comments

A type-safe solution would be to use:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<
     boost::variant<sockaddr_in,
                    sockaddr_in6>
     > sharedSockaddr;

// helper function for interaction with C
sockaddr* getSockaddr(sharedSockaddr addr) {

    struct printer : boost::static_visitor<>
    {
       sockaddr* out;

       void operator()(const sockaddr_in& t)
       {
          out = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&t);
       }

       void operator()(const sockaddr_in6& t)
       {
          out = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&t);
       }
    };

    printer p;
    boost::apply_visitor(p, *addr);
    return p.out;
}
```

Use `sharedSockaddr`s within your code and use `getSockaddr` whenever you need to obtain a `sockaddr*` to pass to the C API.

Comment: `boost::shared_array` is exactly what I was looking for, will the type in the template differing from the `unsigned char []` matter?

Comment: You should assume that it does matter. Why aren't you trying to be type-safe here and doing those strange casts, anyway?

Comment: I cannot pass a `boost::variant` to C code (Linux BSD sockets API).

Comment: You can't pass a `shared_pointer` too. :-) How about: store it as `variant` and just `reinterpret_cast` it to `sockaddr*` as late as possible to keep *your* code clean and safe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6188/discussion-between-unixman83-and-kos)

Comment: What is "as late as possible" ? When receiving `sockaddr`s from `recvfrom()` or `accept()`, "as late as possible" is nearly after the construction. This is what you get when you use object oriented API from C.

Answer (score 3):

To be on the safe side, you should use a custom deleter to do a `reinterpret_cast` back to the original pointer type before deleting:

```
boost::shared_ptr<struct sockaddr> addr(
    reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr *>(
        (ipv6 ? new unsigned char [sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)]
              : new unsigned char [sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)])
    ),
    [](struct sockaddr* ptr) {
        delete[] reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(ptr);
    }
);
```

If your compiler does not support lambdas, you can use a regular function instead.

```
void delete_the_socket(struct sockaddr* ptr) {
    delete[] reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the operator new() directly?

```
boost::shared_ptr<struct sockaddr> addr(
    ipv6 ? static_cast<struct sockaddr*>(::operator new(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)))
         : static_cast<struct sockaddr*>(::operator new(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)))
);
```

Comment: `static_cast` won't work here: `struct sockaddr_in6` and `sockaddr_in` are C structs that are designed to be casted to `struct sockaddr` using C casts, they do not inherit from `struct sockaddr`. Think of this as C-based OO programming.

Comment: @BatchyX That's exactly the reason the operator new is used. The return type of `::operator new()' is void* and static_cast works. The only difference is that the operator new is used instead of malloc(), since the default deleter of shared_ptr frees the memory with 'delete'

Comment: According to the standard, only pointers obtained from the `new` operator can be passed to the `delete` operator (with exceptions for types with virtual destructors, which C structures do not have).  The `::operator new` allocation function is not the same as the `new` operator.