# Implementing a int stack in C++

Tags: c++, oop, stack, operator-overloading

I came across a exercise on the web, this is the text:

> Write a class int_stack  that will manage a stack of integers. The
>   integers values will be stored in  a dynamically allocated array.
>
> This class will propose the following member functions :
>
> int_stack (int n) constructor that will dynamically allocate n
>   integers,
>
> int_stack ( )  constructor allocating 20 integers,
>
> ~ int_stack ( )  destructor,
>
> int empty ( )    the return value is 1 if the stack is empty, 0
>   otherwise,
>
> int full ( )  the return value is 1 if the stack is full, 0 otherwise,
>
> void operator < (int p)  pushes (add) the p value on the stack,
>
> int operator >(int p)  returns (and remove) the value on the top of
>   the stack

I've tried to implement it, but the > (pull) operator won't work.

Here's my code:

int_stack.h

```
class int_stack
{
private:
    int* stack;
    unsigned int n, p;
    void init(unsigned int n);

public:
    int_stack(unsigned int n);
    int_stack();
    ~int_stack();
    int empty();
    int full();
    void operator <(int i);
    int operator >(int i);
};
```

int_stack.cpp

```
#include "int_stack.h"

void int_stack::init(unsigned int n)
{
    this->stack = new int[n];
    this->p = 0;
}

int_stack::int_stack(unsigned int n)
{
    this->init(n);
}

int_stack::int_stack()
{
    this->init(20);
}

int_stack::~int_stack()
{
    delete this->stack;
}


int int_stack::empty()
{
    return (this->p == 0 ? 1 : 0);
}

int int_stack::full()
{
    return (this->p == n-1 ? 1 : 0);
}

void int_stack::operator <(int i)
{
    if (!this->full())
        this->stack[p++] = i;
}

int int_stack::operator >(int i)
{
    if(!this->empty())
        return this->stack[p--];
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In what sense does it not work? Compiler error? Run-time error? Or what?

Comment: `p` is number of items, but your array index is `0-(p-1)`.

Comment: This is a rather poor design, so don't put too much effort into implementing it. Using `>` and `<` for push and pop is horrible, and having `empty()` and `full()` return `int` (C++ has `bool`) means that whoever designed it really didn't know what they were doing.

Comment: Using operators for the `push` and `pop` operations is unnatural, and more so as `int operator>(int)`...

Comment: A suggestion on style: none of the `this->`s is needed.

Comment: Don't do bounds checking. The caller must do bounds checking (that's what `full()` and `empty()` are for). If you want to do bounds checking, don't just silently ignore violated bounds conditions but throw an exception instead.

Comment: given the nature of a stack, it would be more efficient for you to implement this as a linked list, since there is no need to have an array that can be indexed. push(n) can just do `top->next = top; top = new whatever(n);`, and pop() can do `int ret = top->value; top = top->next; return ret`

Comment: If you're going to bounds-check (and you *should* if your design is fixed-length as it is), throw exceptions on exceptional conditions (such as an op that would exceed your limit); don't just do nothing.

Comment: The destruction of the array is incorrect.  When you dynamically allocated an array you need to use `delete[] this->stack`, otherwise the behavior is undefined. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4255636/2705293) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to getting the indexing right, the class needs a copy constructor and an assignment operator. As written you'll get multiple deletes of the same data block:

```
int_stack s0;
int_stack s1(s0); // uh-oh
```

Both destructors will delete the array allocated by the constructor for `s0`.

Comment: How can I implement them? After copying p and n I should copy the stack, but how can I do that without making it public?

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti - the copy constructor is a member, so it has access to the private data of the object that it's copying. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several major flaws with you code:

Unless you want to resize the stack every time you push or pop something onto or off of it, respectively, you probably want to use a linked-list- or deque- style storage structure instead of a vector/array-style.

Overloading `operator<` and `operator>` to do what amounts to extraction and insertion is a terrible interface choice.  I would urge against using operators for those operations:

```
void int_stack::push(int i)
{
    // push an element onto the stack
}

int int_stack::pop()
{
    // pop an element off of the stack
}
```

Because you are not implementing it as a linked-list or deque, when you go to push elements, you can (and eventually will) attempt to write outside the bounds of the memory you allocated.

Finally, you do not delete your stack properly.  If you use `new []`, you must also use `delete []`.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of interface is quite bad, but ignoring that fact consider what your members mean, in particular `p`. The index `p` refers to the location *above* the last added element. When you return the value in the `pop` operation you are reading the value from that location, but that location does not have a value:

```
int int_stack::operator >(int i)
{
    if(!this->empty())
        return this->stack[p--];   // <-- predecrement!
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding the interface, `operator<` and `operator>` are unnatural choices for the push and pop operations. When someone reads in code `s < 5` they interpret that you are comparing `s` with 5, not inserting an element into the stack `s`. That is going to be the source of confusion.

Worse than `operator<` is `operator>` defined as `int operator>(int)`. User code to read a value will end up looking as:

```
value = s > 5;
```

That looks like comparing `s` to 5, and storing the result into `value`. Moreover, the actual behavior is completely independent on the argument 5, the same operation can be spelled as `s > -1` or even `s > 5.3`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working implementation I came up with.

It implements a copy constructor and the assignment operator.

Also, the indexing works, and the interface has changed from the `<` and `>` operators to two simple `push(int)` and `int pop()` functions.

It throws exceptions when you try to push/pop over the boundaries.

int_stack.h

```
#include <exception>

class int_stack
{
private:
    int* stack;
    unsigned int n, p;
    void init(unsigned int n);
    void copy(int_stack& other);

public:
    int_stack(unsigned int n);
    int_stack();
    int_stack(int_stack& other);
    int_stack& operator=(int_stack& other);
    ~int_stack();
    int empty();
    int full();
    void push(int i);
    int pop();
    class OutOfBoundariesException: public std::exception {};
};
```

int_stack.cpp

```
#include "int_stack.h"

void int_stack::init(unsigned int _n)
{
    n = _n;
    stack = new int[n];
    p = 0;
}

int_stack::int_stack(unsigned int n)
{
    init(n);
}

int_stack::int_stack()
{
    init(20);
}

int_stack::int_stack(int_stack& other)
{
    copy(other);
}

int_stack& int_stack::operator=(int_stack& other)
{
    copy(other);
    return *this;
}

void int_stack::copy(int_stack& other)
{
    n = other.n;
    p = other.p;
    stack = new int[n];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        stack[i] = other.stack[i];
}

int_stack::~int_stack()
{
    delete[] stack;
}

int int_stack::empty()
{
    return (p == 0 ? 1 : 0);
}

int int_stack::full()
{
    return (p == n ? 1 : 0);
}

void int_stack::push(int i)
{
    if (!full())
        stack[(++p)-1] = i;
    else
        throw new OutOfBoundariesException;
}

int int_stack::pop()
{
    if (!empty())
        return stack[(p--)-1];
    else
        throw new OutOfBoundariesException;

    return 0;
}
```