# Is delete and delete[] equivalent for basic data types

Tags: c++, delete-operator

So during a code review, a colleague of mine used a `double* d = new double[foo];` and then called `delete d`. I told them that they should change it to `delete [] d`. And they stated that the compiler doesn't need that for basic data types. I disagreed.

So I thought I'd prove my point with an experiment:

```
#define NUM_VALUES 10000
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    std::cout << i << "|";
    double* d = new double[NUM_VALUES];
    std::cout << ((void*)d) << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_VALUES; j++)
      d[j] = j;

    delete d;
    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Not only does the memory usage not grow, but d is allocated to the same place every time! (Visual Studio 2010). Is this a quirk of the visual studio compiler? Or is this part of the standard?

Comment: Your colleague is wrong and he should feel bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete vs delete\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255598/delete-vs-delete)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is delete\[\] equal to delete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/is-delete-equal-to-delete)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `new` you need to use `delete`

If you use `new []` you have to use `delete []`

They mean different things. `double* d = new double();` means allocate and construct a double type. `delete d;` means unallocated and destruct a single double type. `double* d = new double[NUM_VALUES];` means allocate `NUM_VALUES` doubles and `delete [] d` means unallocated each of of the `NUM_VALUES` doubles allocated.

Comment: I agree with you Andre, not disputing that. However, that doesn't explain why my experiment doesn't explode. Is it because the behavior isn't defined?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Exactly. `delete`ing a `new[]`ed object causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah so this is a compiler quirk and should NEVER be relied upon. Thanks.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams, Undefined means undefined. The compiler is free to output a program that does this when your run it in the morning and something else in the afternoon. You would not believe the absolutely bizarre things compilers will come up with in the name of optimization, when behavior is "undefined".

Comment: Follow up question: they asked about the underlying implementation: malloc(foo) is always matched by free(foo), reguardless of size. Why should delete and delete [] be differed? (I didn't have an answer, but I did get them to admit I was right, wooo I-told-you-so-moments)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: They're different to allow implementations - and, perhaps more importantly, user-defined replacements - to optimise them separately. A single-object allocator can be significantly more efficient than one which needs to deal with arbitrarily sized allocations.

Answer (score 6):

> I told them that they should change it to `delete [] d`

You were right. Using the wrong form of `delete` gives undefined behaviour.

> Is this a quirk of the visual studio compiler? Or is this part of the standard?

It's quite likely that an implementation will get the memory from the same place for both "single object" and "array" allocations, in which case using the wrong form of `delete` for trivial types will appear to work. It's also quite likely that freeing memory then allocating the same amount might reuse the same memory. None of this is guaranteed by the standard, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right in your disagreement.

As it has been stated many times, `new/delete` and `new[]/delete[]` are two separate, completely independent ways of dynamic memory management. They cannot be mixed (as in using `delete` for memory allocated by `new[]`), regardless of what type they are being used with.

These two mechanisms can easily be physically different, i.e. they can use completely different memory layouts, completely different memory pools and even work with completely different kinds of system-level memory.

All that not even mentioning that at the language level the raw-memory allocation functions used by these mechanisms (`operator new()` functions and the rest) are independently replaceable, which means that even if thoughtless mixing of these operators appears to "work" for basic types in your implementation, it can easily be broken by raw-memory allocation replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the accepted answer to this question [delete vs delete[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255598/delete-vs-delete) quotes the standard, saying that the behavior is undefined. This should satisfy your coworker. There is more discussion here: [Is delete[] equal to delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/is-delete-equal-to-delete).

If he is not convinced, you may remind him that the global `new/delete`, as well as, the global `new[]/delete[]` could be overwritten in those pairs, so even if the `new[]/delete` pair (for basic types) in the VS2010 implementation do no crash, there is absolutely no guarantee that another implementation will not fail.

For example, we have overwritten the global `new[]/delete[]` in debug mode to hide 'end of array markers' to verify usage. We certainly expect `delete[]` to be called on arrays of doubles created with `new[]` for this to work.

However, because I am on old time C++er, I know the source of your coworkers confusion. Think of the simplest implementation of `new/delete` and `new[]/delete[]` using C's `malloc/free` for the backend and direct calls to the constructors/destructors. It is easy to see that for a simple implementation, as the original C++ implementations were, `delete` and `delete[]` were equivalent for types without destructors. A certain folklore has been built up around this, which may be the source of your coworker's statement, but it does not hold up in reality and in fact never did.

Comment: Good find. That answer explains it very well.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the reason it appears to work is that in your implementation:

- They both get their memory from the same source
- As an optimization, for `double` (and presumably some other types) `new[]` doesn't use any memory storing the requested size of the array. For types with destructors `delete[]` needs to know how many objects to destroy, so that size must be stored somewhere.

The fact that this is how a particular implementation behaves is *not* a good reason to rely on that behavior.

The main reason that the code is likely to go wrong on some implementation, somewhere, is if `new[]` allocates space for the array *plus* space for its size, and returns a pointer to the array. `delete[]` then would subtract the space used for the size before freeing the allocation, whereas `delete` would not. Your colleague has chosen to bet on never encountering an implementation that does this with `new double[]`.

This necessary number can *not* always be deduced by the C++ implementation from the value returned by non-standard functions like `malloc_size()`, since that returns the size of the block used to satisfy the allocation, not the size requested. So generally one should expect `new[]` and `delete[]` to use some trick or other, and it's purely a matter of implementation quality which types they avoid it for.

Even if the implementation is smart enough to avoid the need for extra space with an array of `double`, it might have a debugging mode that deliberately detects the error anyway.