# Dynamic memory in a class (Allocating memory and accessing to the elements)

Tags: c++

I have a simple class `aClass`:

```
class aClass
{
public:
    aClass(int size)
    {
        condition = new bool[size];
    }
    ~aClass()
    {
        delete condition;
    }
    bool getCondition(int i) const
    {
        return condition[i];
    }

    void setCondition(bool* condition, int i)
    {
        *(this->condition + i) = *condition;
    }
private:
    bool* condition;
};
```

In fact I defined a bool pointer and using  constructor to allocate memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "aClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    aClass tempVar(10);
    bool *pC;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        *pC = 0;
        tempVar.setCondition(pC, i);
    }
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
         cout  <<  tempVar.getCondition(i);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know what is the problem in this code.

I used gcc version 4.6.3 to compile the code.

Comment: So what's the unexpected behavior?

Comment: I do not have any output.

Comment: One `delete` per `new`. One `delete[]` per `new[]`. Rule of Three. *mumble mumble*

Comment: Oh and you did not actually create the `bool` you assign to in the first loop

Comment: Why is the `setCondition` method so complicated?

Comment: @user1436187 You should not correct the code in your question, nobody will understand what the answers refer to anymore. Please post your corrected code as answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to dereference `pC` although you never initialized the pointer. Probably `pC` should have type `bool`, not `bool*`, at the same time `*pC = 0` should likely be `pC = 0` and `setCondition` should likely take `bool` not `bool*`.

You `delete` although it should be `delete[]`, see here why: [delete vs delete[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255598/delete-vs-delete)

Your code will try to delete allocated memory twice if an instance of `aClass` is copied somewhere. See [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

You should use `std::vector` instead of the manually allocated array.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mutually exclusive problems here:

1. You haven't initialized pC. Do this:

   ```
   int main() {
       ⋮
       bool * pC = new bool;
       ⋮
       delete pC;
   }
   ```

   Actually, raw pointers aren't such a good idea, so this is better:

   ```
       std::unique_ptr<bool> pC(new bool);
       // No delete required.
   ```
2. `setCondition()` doesn't need a pointer parameter at all:

   ```
   class aClass {
       ⋮
       void setCondition(bool cond, int i) {
           condition[i] = cond;
       }
       ⋮
   };

   int main() {
       ⋮
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
           tempVar.setCondition(false, i);
       }
       ⋮
   }
   ```