# How can I put values inside dynamic arrays of arrays and also delete them in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, delete-operator

Please keep in mind that I can't use classes or vectors, only arrays.

Anyway I have something like this so far:

```
int** arrays = new int*[10]; 
arrays[0] = new int[99]; 
arrays[1] = new int[47];
```

I'm not entirely sure but I think it would be possible to put values within the array that is getting pointed to the same way you would for a 2D array.

So would something like this work?

```
arrays[1][30] = 5;
```

Also if I wanted to delete one of the arrays (not the array pointer) would it be possible to do:

```
delete[] arrays;
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/936702/1141471) may help

Comment: You could make life a lot easier for yourself by doing `std::vector< std::vector<int> > arrays(10);  arrays[0].resize(99); arrays[1].resize(47);` etc.

Comment: I got it. Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

In C++ every call to new should have matching call to delete. So when you initialize array

```
int **arrays = new int*[10];
arrays[0] = new int[99]; 
arrays[1] = new int[47];
```

you have to delete it with

```
delete [] arrays[0];
delete [] arrays[1];
delete [] arrays;
```

In general case read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936709/1141471) answer and whole thread.

A call to

```
arrays[1][30] = 5;
```

is fine because memory has already been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

In order: Yes it would (with risks), and no it won't.

For the first, you need to remember (as **always**) how many elements are in the array so you don't run off the end. One each way might be to use a structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int len;
    int* contents;
} FiniteArray;
```

Then make `int** arrays` actually be an array of `FiniteArray` structures, itself a `FiniteArray*`.

If you're 100% set on using arrays, you still can, just keep lengths around at all times. Don't forget, of course: you need the number of elements in `arrays` too!

For the second part with `delete[]`, that will delete your array of arrays **but will leave the rest of the memory allocated!**

You are correct in that, when you use `new` for an array, you use `delete[]`. Otherwise, for objects, use `delete`, etc etc. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255598/delete-vs-delete). Yes, I know it's a duplicate, but I thought it explains this better than what it's marked duplicate of.

Anyway, you will need to first deallocate the individual arrays if you want to delete `arrays`. In your case,

```
delete[] arrays[0];
delete[] arrays[1];
delete[] arrays;
arrays = NULL; // always a good idea!
```

Just to delete one array, say, the first one,

```
delete[] arrays[0];
arrays[0] = NULL; // always a good idea!
```