# Deleting a dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

So I'm used to memory management in C where `free(pointer)` will free up all space pointed to by `pointer`. Now I'm confusing myself when attempting to do something simple in C++.

If I have a 2D array of doubles allocated in a manner similar to this

```
double** atoms = new double*[1000];
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  atoms[i] = new double[4];
```

what would be the correct method of freeing the memory on the heap allocated by new?

My thoughts were originally this (because my brain was thinking in C):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  delete atoms[i];
delete atoms;
```

But I had forgotten the existence of the `delete[]` operator so I believe the correct method is as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  delete[] atoms[i];
delete[] atoms;
```

Is it important to understand the difference between the `delete` and `delete[]` operators? Or can I just assume that whenever I allocate an array with `ptr = new x[]` I must also deallocate it with `delete[] ptr`?

Comment: The version with `delete []` is valid. If you call `delete []` for non array object, it is an ub. You can see in other SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255598/delete-vs-delete

Comment: Thanks, I had trouble finding posts like that for some reason... but that pretty much clears it up. I marked this as a duplicate of that question

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In reality, an array of pointers pointed to by a pointer is still an array of integral data types or numbers to hold the memory addresses. You should use `delete[]` for both.

Also, yes, a `new[]` implies a `delete[]`.

When you create an array of arrays, you're actually creating an **array of numbers** that happen to hold the memory address for another **array of numbers**. Regardless, they're both arrays of numbers, so delete both with `delete[]`.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a625b672b66f6ce

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    //Hey, pointers have a finite size, no matter the indirection level!
    std::cout << "sizeof(int*): " << sizeof(int*) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(int**): " << sizeof(int**) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(int***): " << sizeof(int***) << std::endl;

    //Create an array of pointers that points to more arrays
    int** matrix = new int*[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = new int[5];
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = i*5 + j;
        }
    }

    //Print out the matrix to verify we have created the matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << matrix[j][i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    //Free each sub-array
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        delete[] matrix[i];   
    }
    //Free the array of pointers
    delete[] matrix;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the type of a pointer is not necessarily an `int` or a `long long` or any other type. The standard defines specific types you can cast to that are arithmetic types: `std::intptr_t` and `std::uintptr_t`. Because of size differences (and possibly some REALLY weird stuff, if you can imagine a weird architecture where pointers are `double`), `int` and `std::intptr_t` could possibly be different sizes (e.g. 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `std::uintptr_t` values).