# c++ munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error

Tags: c++

In my program I have one dynamically allocated array of structures. I initialize all the values immediately and then print them. After it I delete whole array. The program is simple and it works. But after it end printing values of last structure, it also prints an error ('9' is the program name):

> ** Error in './9': munmap_chunk(): ivalid pinter: 0x00e34010 ***
>
> Aborted

I read about this error and it occurs when you try to double free the memory or to access sth in a wrong wat, but I don't see antyhing wrong in my code. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct CandyBar
{
    string brand;
    double weight;
    int calories;
};

int main()
{
    CandyBar *candyArr = new CandyBar [3]
    {
        {"Mandy", 3.2, 220},
        {"Bandy", 5.2, 102},
        {"Candy", 22.3, 209}
    };

    cout << "1: " << (*candyArr).brand << ", " << (*candyArr).weight << ", " << (*candyArr).calories << endl;
    cout << "2: " << (*(candyArr+1)).brand << ", " << (*(candyArr+1)).weight << ", " << (*(candyArr+1)).calories << endl;
    cout << "3: " << (*(candyArr+2)).brand << ", " << (*(candyArr+2)).weight << ", " << (*(candyArr+2)).calories << endl;
    
    delete candyArr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are calling `delete` on the array, you need to call `delete [] `

Comment: Try: delete[] candyArr; to delete an array

Comment: You can also read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255598/delete-vs-delete