# c++: I want 2, 4, 6 to display... instead I think address numbers are displaying?

Tags: c++

I want 2, 4, 6 to display... instead I think address numbers are displaying?

What do I need to do to correct and why?
Thanks

(purpose... to demonstrate ability to change array space and still keep the base of the array)

```
    int *line;

    line = new int;
    line[0] = 2;
    line = new int;
    line[1] = 4;
    line = new int;
    line[2] = 6;
    line = new int;
    printf("%d  %d  %d", line[0], line[1], line[2]);
```

Comment: Well you're sure clobbering that heap good.. Not to mention the FOUR memory leaks trying to display THREE numbers...

Comment: http://augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/arr.html

Comment: If you want to "change the array space and keep the base" (I suppose you mean the "initial segment"?), you won't get around copying the old array into a newly allocated area. By the way, there's a class called `std::vector<int>` which does precisely that for you ;-)

Comment: Let me guess, you come from a background in java or c#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
int *line;

line = new int[3];
line[0] = 2;
line[1] = 4;
line[2] = 6;
printf("%d  %d  %d", line[0], line[1], line[2]);
delete[] line;
```

Points to notice:

```
line = new int[3]; // here you are supposed to specify the size of your new array
...
delete[] line; // whenever you use new sometype[somevalue]; 
               // you must call delete[] later on to free the allocated resources.
```

Also take a look at this question in SO:

[delete vs delete[] operators in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting the pointer `line` at each `new int`. And you're leaking the memory from the one before it.

Also, since you're only allocating one int, only `line[0]` is defined.
Accessing `line[1]` and `line[2]` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You declare an `int*` and allocate an `int` with `new`.  At this point `line` contains an address that points to the `int`.

Accessing `line[1]` and `line[2]` are crashes waiting to happen because those locations contain garbage.  You never allocated memory at those places.

Answer (score 2):

Repeat after me: "This is not Java. I will not use `new` without good reason."

For an array of three ints, you just want something like:

```
int line[] = {2, 4, 6};
```

To print them out, you normally want to use `std::cout` instead of `printf`:

```
std::cout << line[0] << " " << line[1] << " " << line[2];
```

Note, in particular, that there's no reason to use `new` for this task at all.

Answer (score 1):

The line `line = new int` replaces the thing `line` points to with a newly allocated piece of the stack of size `int`.