# If i allocated block of memory using new operator in C++,how to deallocate it without using square braces

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int *p = new int[7];
   delete p;

   return 0;
}
```

Can i deallocate entire block of memory like this in C++?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `new` much be matched `delete`, and `new[]` must be matched by `delete[]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046571/c-delete-array-memory-without-brackets-still-works ... in short: no, it does not work, it is undefined behaviour

Comment: And if you're not required to, don't use `new[]` at all. Instead use either [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or possibly (depending on use-case and requirements etc.) [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: start using vectors and lists now.

Answer (score 2):

Deallocating array allocated with `new[]` without square brackets `delete[]` is undefined behavior by standard, that means it may seem to work sometimes or it may conjure demons out of your nose sometimes. There are no compiler extensions that make additional guarantees about it.

Use `std::vector` when you need dynamic arrays.