# What is wrong with this operator overloading code?

Tags: c++, debugging

What is wrong with this c++ code?

It compiles, but, it doesn't run.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
private:
    int *x;
    int *y;
public: 
    MyClass()
    {
        x = new int[1]; *x = 0;
        y = new int[1]; *y = 0;
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        if(x != NULL)
        {
            delete [] x;
            x = NULL;
        }
        if(y != NULL)
        { 
            delete [] y;
            y = NULL;
        }
    }
    MyClass operator=(MyClass & rhs)
    {
        MyClass temp;
        temp.Set(rhs.x[0], rhs.y[0]);
        return temp;
    }
    void Set(int a, int b)
    {
        if(x != NULL)
        {           
            *x = a;
        }
        if(y != NULL)
        {           
            *y = b;
        }
    }
    void Show()
    {
        cout<<x[0]<<y[0]<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass o1;
    o1.Set(10, 20);
    o1.Show();

    MyClass o2;
    o2 = o1;
    o2.Show();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the actual crash may be caused by the mismatched deallocation of the array as mentioned by rlbond's answer, there is another subtler alternative:

`operator=` returns a copy (not a reference as is conventional), which created using the default copy constructor. In this example it is not used and so a temporary is created. The temporaries `x` and `y` are pointing to the same memory as the copy, since the copy constructor is not defined. When the temporary is destroyed its `x` and `y` are deleted - then later `o2` is destroyed resulting in the same memory getting deallocated twice.

It's worth noting that there's still a lot that can go wrong with this class, and it needs some further love and attention. Also worth seeing how we can find this error.

Here's what I get when pushing it through the [pc-lint online linter](http://gimpel-online.com//cgi-bin/genPage.py?srcFile=diy.cpp&cgiScript=analyseCode.py&title=Do-It-Yourself%20Example%20%28C%2B%2B%29&intro=This%20example%20allows%20you%20to%20specify%20your%20own%20C%2B%2B%20code.&compilerOption=online32.lnt&includeOption=%7B%7BquotedIncludeOption%7D%7D).
Note that this includes the problem causing the crash, and a lot of other things that need fixing.

```
 1  #include <iostream>
 2  
 3  using namespace std;
 4  
 5  class MyClass
 6  {
 7  private:
 8      int *x;
 9      int *y;
10  public: 
11      MyClass()
12      {
13          x = new int[1]; *x = 0;
14          y = new int[1]; *y = 0;
15      }
16      ~MyClass()
17      {
18          if(x != NULL)
19          {
20              delete x;
21              x = NULL;
22          }
23          if(y != NULL)
24          { 
25              delete y;
26              y = NULL;
27          }
28      }
29      MyClass operator=(MyClass & rhs)
        _
30      {
```

diy.cpp  30  Info 1722:  assignment operator for class 'MyClass' does not return a reference to class

diy.cpp  30  Info 1720:  assignment operator for class 'MyClass' has non-const parameter

```
31          MyClass temp;
32          temp.Set(rhs.x[0], rhs.y[0]);
33          return temp;
34      }
35      void Set(int a, int b)
36      {
37          if(x != NULL)
38          {           
39              *x = a;
40          }
41          if(y != NULL)
42          {           
43              *y = b;
44          }
45      }
46      void Show()
47      {
48          cout<<x[0]<<y[0]<<endl;
49      }
                _
13          x = new int[1]; *x = 0;
```

diy.cpp  13  Info 1733:  new in constructor for class 'MyClass' which has no copy constructor

```
20              delete x;
```

diy.cpp  20  Warning 424:  Inappropriate deallocation (delete) for 'new[]' data

```
25              delete y;
```

diy.cpp  25  Warning 424:  Inappropriate deallocation (delete) for 'new[]' data

```
33          return temp;
```

diy.cpp  33  Info 1772:  Assignment operator 'MyClass::operator=(MyClass &)' is not returning *this

```
34      }
```

diy.cpp  34  Warning 1529:  Symbol 'MyClass::operator=(MyClass &)' not first checking for assignment to this

diy.cpp  34  Info 1764:  Reference parameter 'rhs' (line 29) could be declared const ref

diy.cpp  34  Warning 1539:  member 'MyClass::x' (line 8) not assigned by assignment operator

diy.cpp  34  Warning 1539:  member 'MyClass::y' (line 9) not assigned by assignment operator

```
48          cout<<x[0]<<y[0]<<endl;
```

diy.cpp  48  Warning 613:  Possible use of null pointer 'MyClass::x' in left argument to operator '[' [Reference: file diy.cpp: line 37]

diy.cpp  48  Warning 613:  Possible use of null pointer 'MyClass::y' in left argument to operator '[' [Reference: file diy.cpp: line 41]

```
49      }
```

diy.cpp  49  Info 1762:  Member function 'MyClass::Show(void)' could be made const

```
50  };
51  
52  int main()
53  {
54      MyClass o1;
55      o1.Set(10, 20);
56      o1.Show();
57  
58      MyClass o2;
59      o2 = o1;
60      o2.Show();
61  }
62
```

Comment: Hey, this is a nice tool!

Comment: I am amazed!   This is a new vision for me. Can it be or should it be used professionally?

Comment: They have a commercial PCLint product that can be used professionally. It's much more powerful than the online demo, being able to process whole projects.  (I'm not affiliated with them in any way - just appreciate their product).

Answer (score 4):

The only obvious error I can see is that you allocated `x` and `y` as arrays, so you need to use `delete [] x;` instead of `delete x;`, and the same for `y`. The assertion seems to also indicate that it is throwing during deletion, as the file mentioned in the assertion message is `dbgdel.cpp`, and it is checking whether a block type is valid (most likely, this checks whether a block to be deleted is actually an array block or a single instance)

You also don't need those checks against NULL; `new` always succeeds or throws an exception.

More information: [delete vs delete[] operators in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c)

**EDIT**: Also, you need to define a copy constructor. See the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: I think its a little more subtle. I think `operator=` is returning a copy, which is using the _default_ copy constructor, the temporary returned by `operator=` is destructing, resulting in the same memory getting deallocated twice.

Comment: Ah yes, that seems like the underlying issue.