# Segmentation fault (Core Dumped) C++ Beginner

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault

So, I am new to C++. I've researched Segmentation Fault (core dumped), memory allocation, and new/delete although I am having trouble understanding the concepts. I do believe my problem lies with memory allocation though and that's why I thought "delete" would have solved my problem. May someone please push me in the right direction?

**Input**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct CandyBar
{
    string name;
    double weight;
    int calories;
} ;

int main()
{
    CandyBar* backpack = new CandyBar[3];
    backpack[0] = {"Choco Chalk", 5.1, 725};
    backpack[1] = {"Twisty String", 1.8, 300};
    backpack[2] = {"Gummy Nums", 4.4, 475};

    cout << "Name\t\tWeight\tCalories" << endl << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        cout << backpack[x].name << "\t" << backpack[x].weight << "\t" << backpack[x].calories << endl;
    }

    delete backpack;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Name            Weight    Calories

Choco Chalk     5.1       725
Twisty String   1.8       300
Gummy Nums      4.4       475
(Segmentation fault) core dumped
```

Comment: `x < 4` vs `new CandyBar[3]`.

Comment: @Evert I believe you are suggesting I make it `x < 3` and it resulted in an error having to do with `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`.

Comment: `backpack` is an array: `delete [] backpack` of course.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two bugs:

- Your loop `for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)` will iterate through x values 0, 1, 2, 3.  However, since you allocated `backpack` with `new Candybar[3]`, `backpack` points to only enough memory to hold 3 `CandyBar`s, namely `backpack[0], backpack[1], backpack[2]`.  As it stands, on its fourth time through, your loop will attempt to access `backpack[3]`, which is off the end of the array.
- When you allocate memory with `new[]` (as you did since you allocated an *array* of `CandyBar`), you have to deallocate it with `delete[]`, not just plain `delete`.  See [delete vs delete[] operators in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c).

When I changed your loop exit condition to `x < 3` and your deallocation to `delete[] backpack;`, the program worked for me.

Comment: @Voozio Memo: if your array is of size `n` use `x < n`  (strictly less than array size) as a loop condition.