# Array of classes is corrupting data

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am attempting to make an AI similar to [NEAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution_of_augmenting_topologies) using C++. However, I have run into a problem with getting the population to work correctly. When I use an array of custom objects, some of the data stored in each of the objects' properties is being corrupted. The data inside each of the connections in connections is set to `0xDDDDDDDD` after the net is assigned. When I test the given properties inside the constructor it seems fine but when it is assigned within the population array (in this case `t`) all of the data is set to `0xDDDDDDDD` similarly to if it were deleted.

```
    // neat network.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class node
{
public:
    int id;
    double value;
    node()
    {
        id = 0;
        value = 0;
    }
    node(int n)
    {
        id = n;
        value = 0;
    }
    void apply(double v)
    {
        value = v;
    }
    node copy()
    {
        return node(id);
    }
};

class connection
{
public:
    double weight;
    int in;
    int out;
    connection(int i, int o, double w=0)
    {
        in = i;
        out = o;
        weight = w;
        int r = rand();
        weight = ((double)(r % 2000) - 1000.0) / 1000.0;
        srand(r);
    }
    connection()
    {
        in = 0;
        out = 0;
        weight = 0;
    }
    void mutate()
    {
        weight += (double)((rand() % 50 - 2) / 1000);
    }
    connection copy()
    {
        connection ret = connection(in, out);
        ret.weight = weight;
        return ret;
    }
};

double sigmoid(double n)
{
    return 1 / (exp(-n) + 1);
}

class net
{
public:
    double* position;
    int quant;
    node* nodes;
    int* inpernode;
    connection* connections;
    int connlen;
    int inn;
    int ut;
    net(int ins, int outs, int cn=0)
    {
        inn = ins;
        ut = outs;
        quant = ins+outs;
        nodes = new node[quant];
        position = new double[quant];
        connections = new connection[ins*outs];
        inpernode = new int[quant];
        for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++)
        {
            nodes[i] = node(i);
            if (i < ins)
            {
                position[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                position[i] = 1;
            }
            inpernode[i] = 0;
        }
        int c = 0;
        connlen = ins * outs;
        for (int i = 0; i < ins; i++)
        {
            for (int j = ins; j < quant; j++)
            {
                connections[c] = connection(i, j);
                //std::cout << connections[c].weight << " ";
                inpernode[j]++;
                c++;
            }
        }
        //std::cout << connections[0].in << std::endl;
    }
    net()
    {
        connections = new connection();
        connlen = 0;
        inn = 0;
        inpernode = new int();
        quant = 0;
        nodes = new node();
        position = new double();
        ut = 0;
    }
    ~net()
    {
        delete[] position;
        delete[] nodes;
        delete[] connections;
        delete[] inpernode;
    }
    double* apply(double* inputs)
    {
        bool* finished = new bool[quant];
        //std::cout << connections[0].in;
        bool* cfinished = new bool[connlen];
        int* ndone = new int[quant];
        bool alldone=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < connlen; i++)
        {
            cfinished[i] = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++)
        {
            finished[i] = i<inn;
            ndone[i] = 0;
            nodes[i].value = 0;
            if (i < inn) {
                nodes[i].value = inputs[i];
            }
        }
        while (!alldone)
        {
            alldone = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < connlen; i++)
            {
                //std::cout << quant;
                if (finished[connections[i].in] && !cfinished[i])
                {
                    alldone = false;
                    nodes[connections[i].out].value += connections[i].weight * sigmoid(nodes[connections[i].in].value);
                    cfinished[i] = true;
                    ndone[connections[i].out]++;
                    if (ndone[connections[i].out] == inpernode[connections[i].out])
                    {
                        finished[connections[i].out] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        double* outs = new double[ut];
        for (int i = inn; i < inn + ut; i++)
        {
            outs[i - inn] = sigmoid(nodes[i].value);
        }
        return outs;
    }
    net copy()
    {
        net ret = net(inn, ut);
        ret.quant = quant;
        ret.connlen = connlen;
        for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++)
        {
            ret.position[i] = position[i];
            ret.nodes[i] = nodes[i].copy();
            ret.inpernode[i] = inpernode[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < connlen; i++)
        {
            ret.connections[i] = connections[i].copy();
        }
        return ret;
    }
    net mutate()
    {
        net ret = copy();
        for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++)
        {
            if (rand() % 20 == 19)
            {
                connections[i].mutate();
            }
            if (rand() % 333 == 332)
            {
                nodes[quant] = node(quant);
                int temp = connections[i].out;
                connections[i].out = quant;
                connections[connlen] = connection(quant, temp);
                quant++;
                connlen++;
            }
        }
        if (rand() % 33 == 32)
        {
            bool done = false;
            int tries = 200;
            while (!done)
            {
                tries--;
                if (tries < 0)
                    done = true;
                int inc = rand() % quant;
                if (position[inc] == 1)
                    continue;
                int utc = rand() % quant;
                if (position[inc] > position[utc])
                    continue;
                bool found = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < connlen; i++)
                {
                    if (connections[i].in == inc && connections[i].out == utc)
                        found = true;
                }
                if (!found)
                {
                    connections[connlen] = connection(inc, utc);
                    connlen++;
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(2002);
    /*net test = net(2, 1);
    net test2 = net(2, 1);
    std::cout << test.connections[0].weight << " " << test.connections[1].weight << std::endl;
    std::cout << test2.connections[0].weight << " " << test2.connections[1].weight << std::endl;
    double ins[] = { 0,0 };
    double* cp = test.apply(ins);
    std::cout << cp[0]<<" ";
    cp = test2.apply(ins);
    std::cout << cp[0];*/
    net t[1];
    t[0] = net(2, 1);
    std::cout << t[0].inn << " " << t[0].ut << std::endl;
    std::cout << t[0].connections[0].in << " " << t[0].connections[0].weight << std::endl;
    /*net pop[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pop[i] = net(2, 1);
        std::cout << pop[i].connections[0].in << " " << pop[i].connections[1].in << " " << std::endl;
    }
    int* scores = new int[100];
    for (int gen = 0; gen < 100; gen++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            scores[i] = 0;
            double inp[] = { 0, 0 };
            double* t = pop[i].apply(inp);
            if (t[0] < .1)
                scores[i]++;
            inp[1] = 1;
            t = pop[i].apply(inp);
            if (t[0] > .9)
                scores[i]++;
            inp[0] = 1;
            inp[1] = 0;
            t = pop[i].apply(inp);
            if (t[0] > .9)
                scores[i]++;
            inp[1] = 1;
            t = pop[i].apply(inp);
            if (t[0] < .1)
                scores[i]++;
            if (scores[i] == 4)
            {
                std::cout << "Solved" << gen;
                return 0;
            }
            scores[i] -= pop[i].connlen + pop[i].quant;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            sum += scores[i];
        double avg = (double)(sum / 100);
        net newpop[100];
        int nplen = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (scores[i] > avg)
            {
                newpop[nplen++] = pop[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nplen; i++)
        {
            pop[i] = newpop[i];
        }
        for (int i = nplen; i < 100; i++)
        {
            pop[i] = pop[i % nplen].mutate();
        }
    }*/
    return 0;
}

// Run program: Ctrl + F5 or Debug > Start Without Debugging menu
// Debug program: F5 or Debug > Start Debugging menu

// Tips for Getting Started: 
//   1. Use the Solution Explorer window to add/manage files
//   2. Use the Team Explorer window to connect to source control
//   3. Use the Output window to see build output and other messages
//   4. Use the Error List window to view errors
//   5. Go to Project > Add New Item to create new code files, or Project > Add Existing Item to add existing code files to the project
//   6. In the future, to open this project again, go to File > Open > Project and select the .sln file
```

Comment: `0xDD` is used by Microsoft's runtime to mark freed memory

Comment: I am aware of that but I am not sure why it is freeing up that memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)   wrt to `net` with this line `t[0] = net(2, 1);`   Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11

Comment: The code works when I remove the destructor. How am I supposed to delete nodes and connections.

Comment: Your class `net` manages dynamically allocated memory.   Search for information on "rule of three" or (more modern) "rule of five" in context of C++ -  one of those rules needs to be followed for class `net`.

Comment: It will always give me an error when I attempt to use delete[] in my program, and will have other memory errors (I assume because I run out of memory too fast) if I cannot delete them.

Comment: Don’t use raw pointers unless you’re implementing a new kind of memory resource (which you aren’t).  Don’t call `srand` repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Notes in random order

#### * Weight is ignored / multiple calls to `srand`

```
connection(int i, int o, double w=0)
{
  in = i;
  out = o;
  weight = w;

  int r = rand();
  weight = ((double)(r % 2000) - 1000.0) / 1000.0;
  srand(r);
}
```

The user specified weight is **always overwritten** with a random value.

You should probably write two different constructors:

```
connection(int i, int o)
  : weight((static_cast<double>(rand() % 2000) - 1000.0) / 1000.0),
    in(i), out(o)  
{
}

connection(int i, int o, double w) : weight(w), in(i), out(o) {}
```

Consider that multiple calls to `srand` [must be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/3235496).

Also `srand` doesn't work the way you seem to think. The initial call to `rand` returns a *well defined value* that is then used as seed: this seed *is not random at all* so there isn't any *randomness* in chain of calls to `srand` / `rand`.

Moreover intermixed calls to `srand` could affect quality of `rand` (which already in itself isn't great).

#### * `mutate` always returns `0`

```
void mutate()
{
  weight += (double)((rand() % 50 - 2) / 1000);
}
```

it should probably be:

```
void mutate()
{
  weight += (double)((rand() % 50 - 2)) / 1000;
}
```

#### * Deallocation

```
~net()
{
  delete[] position;
  delete[] nodes;
  delete[] connections;
  delete[] inpernode;
}
```

This assumes that `position`, `nodes`, `connections`, `ipernode` are array of objects but they could be a single object, e.g.:

```
net()
{
  connections = new connection();
  inpernode = new int();
  nodes = new node();
  position = new double();

  // ...
}
```

(see [delete vs delete[] operators in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2425728/3235496)).

## Reported issue

```
net t[1];
```

constructs a single `net` object calling `net()`.

```
t[0] = net(2, 1);
```

has (at least) four effects:

1. creates a new `net` object (`net(2, 1)`);
2. deletes the existing `t[0]` object;
3. copies `net(2, 1)` inside `t[0]`;
4. deletes `net(2, 1)`.

Point 2 is problematic (see above: **Deallocation**).

After point 3 you have:

```
t[0].connections ----points to----------> [connection1, connection2]
                                                     ^
                                                     |
net(2, 1).connections ----points to------------------+
```

After point 4:

```
t[0].connections ----points to----------> [freed memory area]

`net(2, 1)` destroyed
```

and the same holds for `position` and `inpernode`.

Now

```
std::cout << t[0].connections[0].in;
```

accesses a freed memory area (the `0xDDDDDDDD` value...).

Deletion of `t[0]` (at the end of `main`) involves the deallocation of an already freed memory block (with an error like *double free detected in tcache 2*).

## TL;DR

- At least add a copy assignment operator and a copy constructor ([rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))) to the `net` class. Also change `net()` to something like:

  ```
  net()
  {
    connections = nullptr;
    connlen = 0;
    inn = 0;
    inpernode = nullptr;
    quant = 0;
    nodes = nullptr;
    position = nullptr;
    ut = 0;
  }
  ```
- All these headaches occur because of *manual* memory management. You could *easily* rewrite the code using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)s and avoid writing any custom copy/move constructors, assignment operators or destructors ([rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three))... and this is the way to go.

PS I've not checked the `net::apply`, `net::mutate`, `net::copy` member functions.