# Dynamic Arrays: Trying to properly expand the dynamic array and am trying to return a not NULL value from function

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

1. I am trying to read the return value of the `pointer_new_values` variable.
2. The `Dynamic Array's elements` double once the array reaches it's `max capacity` using the `growArray` function.

```
#include <iostream>

//Using the returnValue variable in order to be able to see the return value of pointer_new_values. 
int returnValue;
int* growArray(int* pointer_values, int current_size);

int* growArray(int* pointer_values, int current_size)
{
//This dynamic array grows in size here.
    int* pointer_new_values = new int[current_size * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < current_size; ++i)
    {
//This allows me to free memory from pointer values. Using delete. 
        pointer_new_values[i] = pointer_values[i];

    }
//Freeing the allocated memory from pointer_values.
    delete[] pointer_values;
//Returning the pointer_new_values variable, value which is equal to zero.
  *p_new_values = returnValue;
    return p_new_values;
//Here I return the value 0. 
   
// I am trying to read the pointer_new_values integer. From the int function.
}
int main()
{

    int next_element = 0;
    int size = 10;
    int* pointer_values = new int[size];
    int values;
    std::cout << "Please input a number:";
    std::cin >> values;
    while (values > 0)
    {

        if (size == next_element + 1)
        {
            //Now we implement the growArray
            pointer_values = growArray(pointer_values, size);
        }
        pointer_values[next_element] = val;
        std::cout << "Please input another number or exit." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> val;
        //Here I would like to read from the int GrowArray Function.
        std::cout << returnValue; 
//Returns the value of 0. 
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `return pointer_new_values; pointer_new_values = returnValue;` -- See anything wrong with the order of these two lines?  Second, the correct form is `delete []`, not just `delete`.

Comment: There's a growing array already present in standard C++. It's called [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: I did as you said it returned 0. Thank you.

Comment: I know vectors exist.

Comment: @Doomed Then why not use `std::vector` for this?

Comment: *I know there is an alternative called vectors but I want to learn more about dynamic arrays first* -- Then create a `vector` class instead of global functions.

Comment: Because from what I hear is that understanding dynamic arrays shows more mastery of C++. I know it is old school also in unreal engine 4 you use  dynamic arrays for linetraces or raycasting usually for collisions.

Comment: @Doomed -- *understanding dynamic arrays shows more mastery of C++* -- Who told you that?

Comment: And thank you for the advice @TedLyngmo.

Comment: My college Professors. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Sorry to tell you that most college professors know little, if anything about C++.  That has been demonstrated by the many homework questions that come here.

Comment: My professors never used vectors because of their mastery of dynamic arrays I guess they just prefer dynamic arrays or just didn't update their logs.

Comment: How can I improve my question in order to become satisfactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code,

1. Even though array is expanded `size` is not updated
2. All the elements are added to the index zero of the array
3. In function `growArray` expanded array size has to be returned, no statements are executed after encountering of `return`
4. `delete[]` has to be used inorder to release memory allocated using `new[]`. [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c)

I tried to correct some part of your code,

```
#include <iostream>

int* growArray(int* pointer_values, int *size);

int* growArray(int* pointer_values, int* size)
{
    int current_size = *size * 2;
//This dynamic array grows in size here.
    int* pointer_new_values = new int[current_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; ++i)
    {
        pointer_new_values[i] = pointer_values[i];

    }
    delete[] pointer_values;
    
    *size = current_size;
    
    std::cout<< "grow "<<*size<<std::endl;
    
    return pointer_new_values;
}

int main()
{
    int next_element = 0;
    int size = 1;
    int* pointer_values = new int[size];
    int values;
    std::cout << "Please input a number:";
    std::cin >> values;
    while (values >= 0)
    {
        if (size == next_element + 1)
        {
            //Size is updated on expanding the array
            pointer_values = growArray(pointer_values, &size);

        }

        pointer_values[next_element++] = values;
        //              ^^Here ,elements are added to new index 

        std::cout << "Please input another number or negative value for exit." << endl;
        std::cin >> values;
    }
    
     for (int i = 0; i < next_element; ++i)
    {
       std::cout<< pointer_values[i] << " ";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping understand more about dynamic arrays.

Comment: The flaw in this code is that it does a reallocation when `growArray` is called for a smaller size instead of just reusing the already allocated memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I didn't understand what you mean by re-using the allocated memory. Isn't it contiguous memory location is required?

Comment: @TruthSeeker `growArray(pointer, 20);  growArray(pointer, 1);`  -- What operations will be done in those two successive calls?  You already have memory for 20 items, so why deallocate and reallocate again for 1 item?  A better implementation would have a capacity as well as a size.  That's the flaw I'm referring to.

Comment: @Doomed, If I understand you correctly, `growArray` updates the `size` on array expansion.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: What you have said is correct. Understanding is that `growArray` is called only to expand the array size but not to shrink. @Doomed: please look into the use case of shrinking array and re-using the allocated memory.

Comment: @TruthSeeker Yes.

Comment: The grow array is supposed to double the current array size.

Comment: @TruthSeeker mind if I ask why does return pointer_new_values return 0?

Comment: @Doomed ` return pointer_new_values` is not a returning a value but the pointer of allocated memory.

Comment: @TruthSeeker So it is only returning the memory address?

Comment: @Doomed yes, it is. Please find good [reference books] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). to get the understanding of the language

Answer (score 0):

I did some addition research and I made the dynamic array on much `simpler` and cleaner terms rather then using a function in order to `double` the array's `size`. It is probably unnecessary to return a value from a function anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
//Here is a simpler way of doing everything I described.
int size;
int main()
{
    int pointerAddition = 10;
    int* ten = &pointerAddition;
    do 
    {
        std::cout << "How many indexs do you want?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please enter 0 to exit the loop." << std::endl;
//This allows me to allocate spaces during runtime. 
        std::cin >> size;
        int* dynamic_array = new int[size];
        std::cout << "Enter " << size << " numbers." << std::endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
//Allows you to add an integer to each index of the array.
            std::cin >> dynamic_array[x];
        }
        std::cout << "You entered: " << std::endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
//Prints each index of the array.
            std::cout << dynamic_array[x] << std::endl;
        }
        //Rather then using a function I settled for a simple if statment to keep it simple.
//If the size of the array is greater then or equal to 4 then double the array's size.
        if (size >= 4)
        {
            int size_doubled;
            size_doubled = size * 2;
            //Shows the size of the array doubled.
            std::cout << "The size of the array doubled." << std::endl;
            std::cout << size_doubled << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Ten has been added to the first index of the array." << std::endl;
            for (int y = 0; y < size_doubled; y++)
            {
                //Adds ten to the first index of the array.
                dynamic_array[0] += *ten;
                //Prints out the newly modified array.
                //In order to prove that the indexes have been added during runtime.
                std::cout << dynamic_array[y] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    //Deallocating memory every time the base operation is complete.
        delete[] dynamic_array;
    } while (size != 0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```