# arithmetic std::unique_ptr and void* (get position of element by address)

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a class:

1. Allocate blockSize*maxSize bytes of memory. Has a method which return ptr to free block of memory.
2. I fill this block in `main()` for example (see usage below) and send it back to my class.

**PROBLEM:** How can I get position of sent me back address of initialized data? Because in main() I have `void* ptr`, not `std::unique_ptr`, and arithmetic with method `memoryPool.get()` not possible to use.

```cpp
class A {
private:
    size_t maxBlocks;
    size_t blockSize;
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> memoryPool;

    void *getObjPtr(const size_t pos) const {
        return reinterpret_cast<void *>(memoryPool.get() + pos * blockSize);
    }
    
public:
    A(size_t blockSize, size_t maxBlocks) : blockSize(blockSize), maxBlocks(maxBlocks),
                                            memoryPool(new unsigned char[maxBlocks * blockSize]) {}

    void *getFree() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < maxBlocks; ++i) {
            //check if this block not use (I cut this part)
            return getObjPtr(i);
        }
    }

    size_t getPosition(void *data) {
        //how can I get position of element? 
        // auto pos = ((char*)data - memoryPool.get()) / blockSize; - not works
        // ok there should be C++ style reinterpret_cast, but to short code I skip it
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```cpp
int main() {
    A queue(sizeof(int), 10);

    int *a = static_cast<int *>(queue.getFree());
    *a = 4;
    auto pos = queue.getPosition(a);//want to get position
}
```

What is proper way to do it? Without using `std::unique_ptr` in main?

Comment: Please note that you may not assign a pointer to an array to `std::unique_ptr<T>`, you need `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. It should be `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> memoryPool;` otherwise it will try to use `delete` instead of `delete[]`.

Comment: When I look at `getPosition()`, I wonder what it does. Could you document what semantics it has, what it requires and what guarantees it offers? Of course, I'm assuming a working implementation, but the question remains what it's requirements are.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt In this example it just return the position of element in my memoryPool.  For example, if I fill I-th free position after `getFree()` then I will get `pos = 4` after calling `getPosition(a)`. I suppose that it should just return 
difference between i-th address ptr and started address pointer / blockSize.

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you give an example or two?

Comment: `((unsigned char*)data - memoryPool.get()) / blockSize` looks like it should in fact work. What do you mean when you say "not works" - what outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, you are right, thank you, I'm so 
inattentive

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hmm, I roughly understood what you are talking about, but could advice, where can  I read about? I thought that I allocate a big space `blocksize*blockCount` of 1 bytes, and because of `unique_ptr` it will deletes on a whole. Because it's not array, it space where I get access by knowing only me

Comment: @Mike If you assign the result of `new[]` to `unique_ptr` it has to be a `unique_ptr<T[]>`. If you assign the result of `new` is has to be `unique_ptr<T>`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: @Mike Or maybe the information you are missing is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but you can (and should) remove that `reinterpret_cast` in `getObjPtr`. Every pointer type can be implicitly converted to `void*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I compile your code with Visual C++ 2019, I get this error:

`error C2440: '-': cannot convert from 'unsigned char *' to 'char *'`

If I change your code to cast to `unsigned char*` as per the error message, then it compiles:

`auto pos = ((unsigned char*)data - memoryPool.get()) / blockSize;`

Whether that does what you intend - well, it appears to, but you haven't clearly specified what `getPosition` does, so I can only guess.

Please post the error message in the future, not just say it doesn't work!  It'll help us help you.