# Will delete the pointer to pointer cause the memory leak?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I have a question about C-style string symbolic constants and dynamically allocating arrays.

```cpp
const char** name = new const char* { "Alan" };
delete name;
```

when I try to `delete name` after `new`'ing a piece of memory, the compiler suggest to me to use `delete` instead of `delete[]`. I understand `name` only stores the address of the pointer to the only-read string.

However, if I only `delete` the pointer to pointer (which is `name`), will the string itself cause a memory leak?

Comment: You should `delete` only what you `new`ed and nothing else. No, C-strings should not be `delete`d.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c

Comment: You `delete` what you have `new`ed. In this case, you delete `name`. Keep in mind, that the whole exercise is rather moot. `const char* name = "Alan"` should serve you well and requires no deletions or `new`itions.

Comment: @SergeyA If I'm reading Pavta's link properly would `delete [] name` be appropriate?

Comment: @Ruzihm did you use `new []`?

Comment: @Ruzihm, no, because you did not do `new[]`. Those things always come in pairs.

Comment: It may help to visualize the example as `T* name = new T { "Alan" ); delete name;` where `T` just happens to be `const char *`.

Comment: Ah, I see, you would use `delete [] name;` if you had used `const char ** name = new const char*[1]{"Alan"};` because of the difference between an array of a single element and a pointer. Is that right?

Comment: @Ruzihm, I am actually confusing about `const char*`, I think it is similar to `char[]` which also stores string. Similarly, if I want to delete `const char*`, I should use `detele[]`. Otherwise, I will only delete the pointer to the string, not the string itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments above indicate, you don't need to manage the memory that "Alan" exists in.
Let's see what that looks like in practice.

I made a modified version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

void test() {
    const char** name;
    name = new const char* { "Alan\n" };   
    delete name;
}

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

and then I popped it into [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Edsacb) and it shows what's happening under the hood. (excerpts copied below)

In both clang and gcc, the memory that stores "Alan\n" is in static memory so it always exists. This is how it creates no memory leak even though you never touch it again after mentioning it. The value of the pointer to "Alan\n" is just the position in the program's memory, `offset .L.str` or `OFFSET FLAT:.LC0`.

> clang:
>
> ```
> test():                               # @test()
>         push    rbp
>         mov     rbp, rsp
>         sub     rsp, 16
>         mov     edi, 8
>         call    operator new(unsigned long)
>         mov     rcx, rax
>         movabs  rdx, offset .L.str
>         mov     qword ptr [rax], rdx
>         mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rcx
>         mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
>         cmp     rax, 0
>         mov     qword ptr [rbp - 16], rax       # 8-byte Spill
>         je      .LBB1_2
>         mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 16]       # 8-byte Reload
>         mov     rdi, rax
>         call    operator delete(void*)
> .L.str:
>         .asciz  "Alan\n"
> ```
>
> gcc:
>
> ```
> .LC0:
>         .string "Alan\n"
> test():
>         push    rbp
>         mov     rbp, rsp
>         sub     rsp, 16
>         mov     edi, 8
>         call    operator new(unsigned long)
>         mov     QWORD PTR [rax], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
>         mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
>         mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
>         test    rax, rax
>         je      .L3
>         mov     esi, 8
>         mov     rdi, rax
>         call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
> ```

Comment: I guess I need more knowledge in the future to understand the assembly code, but anyway, thank you.