# Access violation when the object goes out of scope in switch case

Tags: c++, winapi

Ok, then. I started learning C++, and my task is to create a process manager with the  Win32 API. It is going to look like this:

[image]

I have a `TBuffer` class: (Buffer will keep information about the processes)

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <wtypes.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
#define WM_UPDATELIST WM_USER

enum TProcessState { psEmpty, psNew, psRunning, psTerminated, psError };

struct TProcessInfo 
{
    TProcessState State;
    char Name[100];
    HANDLE Handle;
    int PID;
    int UserTime, KenelTime;
};

class TBuffer
{
private:
    HWND Wnd;
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    TProcessInfo Buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
public:
    TBuffer(HWND AWnd);
    ~TBuffer();
    int Count();
    int AddProcess(char *AName);
    void Get(int Id, TProcessInfo &Pi);
    void Set(int Id, const TProcessInfo Pi);
    const char* ProcessStateToString(TProcessState state);
};
```

The class constructor has the following realization:

```cpp
TBuffer::TBuffer(HWND AWnd)
{
    Wnd = AWnd;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
    {
        Buf[i].State = psEmpty;
        Buf[i].Handle = 0;
        Buf[i].Name[0] = 0;
        Buf[i].PID = 0;
        Buf[i].UserTime = 0;
        Buf[i].Handle = 0;
    }
}
```

And the destructor:

```cpp
TBuffer::~TBuffer()
{
    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);
}
```

The method using critical section:

```cpp
void TBuffer::Set(int Id, const TProcessInfo Pi)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    ...
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
}
```

In the main `.cpp` file, I have a global variable:

```cpp
TBuffer *Buffer;
```

And in the `MainWndProc` function where messages are processed, in the case `WM_INITDIALOG` I am asked to create a `TBuffer` class object to initialize the critical section and so on:

```cpp
case WM_INITDIALOG:
{
    TBuffer Buf(hWnd);
    Buffer = &Buf;
    ...
    return TRUE;
}
```

My problem is that, as I read, the class object after `return TRUE` is going out of scope and its destructor is called. That's why the critical section is deleted and then other class methods like `Set()` and `Get()` are not able to enter the critical section. So I'm looking for a way to leave the object in scope. I think that something is wrong in `WM_INITDIALOG` with object creation.

By the way, when the `WM_DESTROY` message is processed, I free the allocated memory for the global variable:

```cpp
case WM_DESTROY:
    delete[] Buffer;
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return TRUE;
```

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except for questions about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: you allocate temporary object in stack ( `TBuffer Buf(hWnd)` ) which of course not valid after exit from scope. and can not be used after this. even more - you  try `delete[]` it despite you not allocate object with `new`.

Comment: The way to allocate a new object in C is to use the `new` operator: `Buffer = new TBuffer(hWnd);`.

Comment: FYI: code like this: `EnterCriticalSection(&cs); ... LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);` is no good if `...` throws an exception.  You would basically have a deadlock thread if it is waiting for the critical section to be released.  Instead of this, use RAII such as `std::lock_guard` or if not that, write a class that automatically calls `LeaveCrititcalSection` on destruction, create an object of that type, and assign `cs` to it.  This is the big advantage that C++ has over C in this regard -- writing this type of code safely becomes much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in your understanding,

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
{
    TBuffer Buf(hWnd);
    Buffer = &Buf;
    ...
    return TRUE; // <-- Buf is destructed here, Buffer is now a dangling pointer
}
```

To allocate something that lives longer than its enclosing scope, allocate it on the heap using `new`:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
{
    Buffer = new TBuffer(hWnd);
    ...
    return TRUE;
}
```

And remember to `delete` later.

Comment: Remember to delete with scalar `delete`, not array `delete[]`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c