# C++ What is the difference between delete and delete [ ]?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

If I allocate an array like this: `int* arr = new int [n];` should I free memory using `delete arr;` or `delete[] arr;`. What's the difference between these two operators in this case (if any)?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c) answer your question?

Comment: In practice, don't allocate arrays like that though. Just use std::vector (it will do the memory managment for you)

Comment: `delete` pairs up with `new`, and `delete[]` pairs up with `new[]`.  In modern C++, neither need to be used (unless you are making your own container or smart pointer).  Instead use `std::vector` or `std::array` or `std::unique_ptr` (or if you have a really good need for it, `std::shared_ptr`).