# What does 'delete [] _v;' mean?

Tags: c++

```
template<>
class CalcHashClass<const char*> {
public:
    CalcHashClass(const char* v) {
        _v = new char[strlen(v) + 1];
        strcpy(_v,v);
    }

    ~CalcHashClass() {
        delete [] _v;
    }

    int hashCode() {
        printf("This is 'template <> class CalcHashClass<const char*>'.\n");
        int len = strlen(_v);
        int code = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            code += (int)_v[i];
        return code;
    }

private:
    char* _v;
};
```

For above code, I am not sure what `delete [] _v;` mean?
In my understanding, _v is a pointer. And to delete it should use `delet _v`, am I right? What does the `[]` mean?

Comment: It means `_v` is an array.  You can see the `[` and `]` in the `new` statement as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how you even got to template specialization if you have not learned about raw-arrays and member variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete x` will only delete the variable x
whereas the `[ ]` indicate to the memory manager that an array was allocated. `delete[] x` will delete the allocated array.

Comment: I like this answer, simple and easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Look at how the object that `_v` points to was allocated:

```
_v = new char[strlen(v) + 1];
```

It uses the `new char[...]` syntax, meaning that it is dynamically allocating an array of `char`. To destroy a dynamically allocated array, you need to use `delete[]`.

The reason that this is necessary is because the compiler cannot tell that `_v` is pointing at an array from the type of `_v` alone. Since `_v` is just a `char*`, there's no reason you couldn't point it at a single dynamically allocate `char`. So `delete[]` tells the compiler that it needs to find out exactly how much space was allocated here and then deallocate all of it.

Answer (score 1):

`delete[]` is called the "array delete operator". It deletes an array allocated using `new[]`.

It is important to note that it is not allowed to use array `delete` with non-array `new` and vice versa.

For more information, see [Why do we even need the "delete[]" operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252515/why-do-we-even-need-the-delete-operator)

As a side note, your class violates the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). You should provide (or disable) the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an array allocated using `new []` you need to use `delete []` if you use just `delete` with memory allocated using `new []` you will have undefined behavior. In the code posted you are allocating using `new []` in your constructor here:

```
_v = new char[strlen(v) + 1];
```

hence the call to `delete []` later on in the destructor.